# Python Messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

```
from tkinter import messagebox
messagebox.showinfo('hello','hello')
while True:
    print('hello')
```

надо чтобы до нажатия на 'да' начинался и продолжался цикл

Comment: Запускайте цикл в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Это как сделать?

Comment: Через модуль threading

Comment: А можно код пожалуйста

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял, то смотри, ты можешь использовать метод `messagebox`'а `askyesno()` благодаря чему у тебе выведется окошко с кнопками ДА/НЕТ. И Вернётся `True` Если пользователям будет нажата ДА, и `False` если нажата Нет

```
from tkinter import messagebox
if messagebox.askyesno('hello','hello'):
    while True:
        print('hello')
```

Comment: Код с ошибкой, да еще не работает как требуется. Зачем разместили?

Comment: @СергейКох А, там отступа под while не было. Теперь пробуйте

Comment: "надо чтобы до нажатия на 'да' начинался и продолжался цикл" - у вас печатать будет только после "да".